# Buying for someone else with reimbursement (UK): is it a sale?

Tags: united-kingdom, commerce

Suppose I buy a Steam game as a gift for someone, as a favor, under the condition I will be reimbursed as soon as possible, and that the sum I'm going to receive only covers my expense.

Under UK law, does exchanging the gift and the reimbursement constitute a sale involving me and the recipient of the gift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

Legally you are acting as an agent for the person buying the game and the sale is between that person and Valve. Practically, you may have a hard time explaining this to Valve.

Comment: As far as Valve is concerned, if the game is being bought as a gift, it is implicit that I intend to give it to another person, though.

Regardless that Valve has no way to tell whether the game is being gifted or I am simply acting as an agent, what would change if Valve could?